# How to include the static JavaScriptCore C library(libJavaScriptCore.a)?

Tags: c, linux, static-libraries, javascriptcore

I was able to compile JavaScriptCore on Linux and I want to use the JavaScriptCore static library.

It is my understanding that in C,  .a files are the static libraries and I need a header file,(.h)  to include a static library to work with my code. As it happens, once compiled, there is `WebKit/WebKitBuild/Release/lib/libJavaScriptCore.a` which I think is the JavaScriptCore static library however the file is not accompanied with a header file like libJavaScriptCore.h.

There is a JavaScriptCore.h somewhere else, is that the header file I'm looking for? How would you include the JavaScriptCore in you C code? (PS: I'm actually using it with Swift through it's C API). Thank you in advance!

Comment: The `.h` file you found is [probably] correct (it usually does _not_ have `lib` prefix). You'll need `#include <JavaScriptCore.h>` in your `.c` file. Then, if (e.g.) lib is `/path_to_lib/WebKit/WebKitBuild/Release/lib/libJavaScriptCore.a` and include file is `/path_to_h/WebKit/WebKitBuild/Release/include/JavaScriptCore.h`, you want: `cc -o mysource mysource.c -I/path_to_h/WebKit/WebKitBuild/Release/include -L/path_to_lib/WebKit/WebKitBuild/Release/lib -lJavaScriptCore` You'll also need similar `-I`, `-L`, `-l` for any swift related files. The paths here are just examples--adjust to suit

Comment: A `.h` just provides declarations/definitions of the functions in the given library so your C code will _compile_ [cleanly]. It does _not_ do anything to "link" to the library. That's what the `-L/-l` compile options do.

Comment: Hmm, I will look at it, thank you. What confused me is that in the JavaScriptCore.h contains other include statements that are like <JavaScriptCore/JSValue.h> and from what I've been reading, in C <library.h> kind of statements mean that it is including from the OS Paths but I need to include a library that is right there in a subfolder so I expected something like "library.h" instead. Also, when I unarchived the libJavaScriptCore.a, the object files are named in a cryptic way, which made me think that there must be some kind of .h file mapping to the correct .o files in the .a file

Comment: There is _no_ relationship between a `.h` file (either full path or file contents) and where a `.a` file is located. You just have to use the correct `-I` options so the subinclude (e.g. `#include <JavaScriptCore/JSValue.h>` will resolve correctly. There is _no_ relationship with the naming of the `.o` files _within_ a `.a` either. Although you're talking about Javascript, it seems like you think there's some relationship like Java `.java` files and `.class` files (within `.jar`)--there isn't. That is, `struct foo` can be in `bar.h` if we wish [IMO, another reason to "unlearn" Java ;-)]

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications! All I want to do is to run some user input JavaScript in  my app made with Swift. On macOS, JavaScriptCore is quite easy to use but since I will run this thing on a Linux server I need to be able to use JavaScriptCore there too but unfortunately JavaScriptCore is not part of the Swift open source and not readily available. As a result, I'm trying to put it together myself. And learning a bit of C in the process! Kind of start liking it.

Comment: Well, Apple S/W that is macOS/iOS specific can be hard to port to other systems. Not because it's inherently difficult, but Apple may publish the source, to be able to say it's open source, but not make it easy to port to non-Apple systems. So, it's pretty admirable that you're willing to take the [initial] pain and tackle this. Since _your_ code is the glue that will hook Swift to Javascript, as an alternative, you could hook up to a [freely] available open source JS interpreter specifically designed for linux. Dealer's choice ...

Comment: Oh I wouldn't give myself that much credit on this one :) The engine is free and OS, just the nice glue to make it work with Swift that is coming by default on macOS/iOS etc is missing and it's kind of a nice exercise as the language the other engines are written on(like C++) is also alien to me.  Thanks for the help, I think I will figure it out eventually!